# Environment Files Vs Git Ignore in Code Repository

Tags: git, angular

For applications which use Angular, we have the option to use environment.ts for differentiating different development environments like Development, Test, and Master. Suppose we have to mask some elements like database credentials which we used in different environments the normal procedure we used to use .gitignore such configuration files which are not available in the repository.

Can anyone suggest which is the standard way for this 
Do we keep git ignore files or keep credentials in the repository using Environment Files of angular?

Comment: I think that it's a bad idea to keep any sensitive information in client code, since it will be shipped to the user's browser, and so be available to them. Further, why would you put database credentials in the user interface? All of your sensitive information belongs in your back-end, secured on a server that you control.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one standard way to handle differences between environments.  Different approaches have different pros and cons.

IF you use .gitignore only, then you forego versioning of environment-specific settings (or have to find an outside-the-repo way to get such versioning).  Also every clone has to be configured with a set of config files.

If you use environment.ts only, then any passwords for any environment used in any configuration file are available to everyone who can read the repo.

Source control mechanisms like .gitignore, framework features like environment.ts, and also build tool capabilities (like resource filtering in Maven) can all play a useful role in a solution that meets your needs, once you've defined those needs for your project.